# Which classes and what moves allow for higher jumping than normal?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For Team Fortress 2, which classes and what moves/weapon loadouts/ allow for higher jumping? I know of the most basic, rocket jumping, but can other classes do something similar?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- **Scout**:

  - Double Jump (default)
  - Atomizer Triple Jump. The damage from this can be negated by Bonk! Atomic Punch. Holding the Winger out increases jump height
  - Force-A-Nature Quadruple Jump
  - Bonk! Jump (use the recoil from an enemy's sentry)
  - Boston Basher/Three-Runed Blade Jump (hit yourself in mid-air)
  - Jumping with the Winger (allows for higher jumps)
- **Soldier**

  - Rocket Jump (jump, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to crouch, and fire  a rocket at your feet in that order really fast) 
    Use the Market Gardner  along with the Rocket Jumper (the penalty that made you take double damage has been removed) to oneshot enemies and suprise foes!
- **Demoman**

  - Stickybomb Jump (fire a sticky at your feet and detonate it. Because of the high damage output of a stickybomb this can do a lot of damage. You can use the Stickyjumper to negate this.
  - Grenade Jump (fire a grenade and run on top of it before it explodes. This is difficult to do)
  - Chargin' Targe/Splendid Screen Jump (run at a ramp like the rock formation right outside BLU's spawn in `cp_degroot` and charge towards it. When you start your crouch hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to go further. This is a bit difficult to learn but it is very useful to kill archers/snipers on the battlements)
  - Loose Cannon Jumping (similar to rocket jumping, but holding down the Loose Cannon's fuse to propel yourself in the air)
- **Engineer**

  - Sentry Jump (fire rockets at your feet with the wrangler in the same motion as a soldier's rocket jump)

    Be careful with this, as I don't think engineers have self-damage resistance (unlike soldiers/demomen) and a rocket does very high damage. This can be used to reach points previously unavailable to you and suprise enemies. One example of this is on `cp_gorge`. At the first control point you can sentry jump onto BLU's second spawn.
  - Mini-sentry Jump (use the minisentry with the wrangler to propel yourself up). 
    This can also be done with a regular sentry gun, however, the minisentry has a higher rate of fire and does less damage.
- **Pyro**

  - Reflect a projecticle at your feet to preform a rocket jump
  - Detonator/Scorch Shot jump (fire a flare at your feet)
- **Medic**

  - If the soldier/demoman you are healing does a rocket/stickyjump and you [are equipped with the Quickfix](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Quick-Fix) you will also be launched upward as well with equal force in the same direction as the patient.
- **All Classes**

  - Pumpkin Jump. On Halloween event maps (specifically `koth_harvest_event`, `cp_manor_event`, `koth_viaduct_event`, and `koth_lakeside_event`), Pumpkin Bombs can be exploded to preform a (highly-self-damaging) rocket jump.
  - Enemy-Assisted Jump. Soldiers shooting rockets at your feet, demomen exploding bombs at your feet, pyros airblasting you, Sentry Gun knockback, can all be used to propell you in the air.
  - Jump Upgrade. Only on MvM missions, and upgradable with credits through the Upgrade Station

Comment: I assume, Engie, that the turret damages you? Could lead to some cool tp spots though.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that any class can surf an enemy rocket/pipe/sticky if they don't die to the explosion.

Comment: You missed needle-jumping, which is available on the PS3 and Xbox360 versions. It was patched out a long time ago on the PC but involves a bug with the syringe gun that causes syringes shot at another players feet to lift them up into the air quite high.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some basic jumps you tend to see pretty often. These should get you started. For (far) more advanced techniques, there is a nice list on the [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jumping).

**Scout**
Once in the air, can jump a second time. Easily done and can easily nearly doube the height or distance of a jump. Can also boost his jumping abilities with the following weapons:
*Force-A-Nature* This shotguns recoil can be used to boost a jump. For more details, see TF2 wiki for [Force Jump](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jumping#Force_Jump)
*Atomizer* With this weapon equipped (doesn't have to be out), the Scout can do another jump in the air. A "tripple jump", if you will. However, this will cost some HP for the final jump.

**Soldier**
This one you already mentioned, but for completeness sake I'll mention it here as well. The Soldier can rocket jump by firing a rocket at his feet as he's jumping. Extra height is gained by crouching while doing the rocket jump. Also, by aiming slightly further off center, the Soldier can control the direction of the jump. Requires some practice.
Once you get the basics down, also try doing another rocet jump off a wall. Mastering this technique will get you further away and to otherwise inaccessable places.

**Demoman**
Can use his sticky bombs to do a "sticky jump". Similar to the Soldiers rocket jump, but with stickies, but easier to do. Especially while running. Just fire a sticky to the ground, run over it, jump and detonate with right click. Once again, crouching adds to the jump and being a bit off center can give you more forward momentum. Also works with Scottish Resistance. Normally you would have to look at the bombs to detonate them with this weapon, but if the bombs are under your feet, it isn't necesary.

**Engineer**
The Engineer can "sentry jump", using the Wrangler that allows him to control the otherwise automatic sentry himself. It's quite simple, altough rather slow so it's rarely done in the midst of battle. Simply build a sentry, jump on top of it, take out the Wrangler and aim it upwards. If you're at the path of the bullets, they should propel you upwards. Can cause a lot of damage, especially if the sentry is high level, but can get the Engineer to some rather interesting places.

You should also remember that crouching during any normal jump can get you that last necesary inch of distance or height, since it will take a split second longer before your feet touch the ground.